# Which is the most frequently played match in football European Cups?

Tags: football, trivia, history, records, uefa

According to [this source](http://www.worldfootball.net/teams/juventus/real-madrid/11/) Juventus and Real Madrid have played 19 times in the past. In [quarter-finals of the 2017/18 UEFA Champions League](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/index.html#/iv/match/2021701) they will play two more times for a total of 21. So,

What is the most frequently played match in European Cups?

Answer (score 3):

The most frequently played match in European Cups is [Bayern Munich Vs Real Madrid](http://www.worldfootball.net/teams/real-madrid/bayern-muenchen/11/) they have met ***24 times up to now***.

[uefa.com](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2450461.html?rss=2450461+Bayern+v+Real+Madrid:+past+meetings,+stats+and+reaction#/) article states:

> Bayern and Real Madrid have met 22 times previously in the European Cup, ...

[foxsports.com](https://www.foxsports.com/soccer/gallery/real-madrid-vs-bayern-munich-champions-league-rivalry-history-041217) article published on Apr 12, 2017 states:

> *No fixture has been played more often in the Champions League or European Cup than this one*. Wednesday’s game will be the 23rd meeting, and the 21st in the knockout stage.

[bundesliga.com](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/news/Bundesliga/noblmd-bayern-munich-real-madrid-a-champions-league-classic-440451.jsp) article states:

> Bayern Munich and Real Madrid ***meet for a record 23rd time in European competition*** ....

[americascardroom.eu](https://www.americascardroom.eu/poker-blog/2017/03/bayern-munich-vs-real-madrid-history-and-breakdown/) article states:

> This match will be the 23rd time both sides face each other, ***making it the most played match-up in the UEFA***.

Other: [Bayern Munich vs Real Madrid is most played game in Champions League history](https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/football/3312820/bayern-munich-real-madrid-champions-league/)

Results of past matches: [Source](http://www.worldfootball.net/teams/real-madrid/bayern-muenchen/11/) [Other](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2450461.html?rss=2450461+Bayern+v+Real+Madrid:+past+meetings,+stats+and+reaction#/)

[image: result]